# Fetch specific data from Database for a product

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I'm using WooCommerce and I need to fetch data from my woocommerce database:

I know, I can get the regular price of an item with this code:

```
$regPrice = $_product->get_regular_price();
```

In the Database the field with the regular price looks like this: _regular_price

I know that the discount looks like this in the database: _bulkdiscount_discount_1

So I thought, that I can get the $discount1 like this:

```
$discount1 = $_product->get_bulkdiscount_discount_1();
```

But unfortunately this is not working. When I try to echo $discount1 using this code `echo "<p>Discount One = $discount1 </p>";` nothing will be "echoed".

What I am doing wrong? 
Are there any Woocommerce Cracks here who can advice me to the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look to the [**`class WC_Product`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html) you will see that this WooCommerce product class include predefined methods like [**`get_regular_price()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_regular_price), but certainly not **`get_bulkdiscount_discount_1()`**. You should need to extend this WC_Product class with new methods and this is a complicated process.

To fetch data from your woocommerce database which key is `'_bulkdiscount_discount_1'` you will have to use WordPress function [**`get_post_meta()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) with a defined product ID this way *(if **`$_product`** is the product object instance)*:

```
// Be sure to get the product ID (Added compatibility with WC 3+)
$product_id = method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ? $product->get_id() : $product->id;
// echo '<p>Product ID: ' . $product_id . '</p>';

// Get the bulk discount1 from wp_postmeta table for this product ID (post ID)
$discount1 = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_bulkdiscount_discount_1', true );
// Displaying the bulk discount 1
echo '<p>Discount One: ' . $discount1 . '</p>';
```

Comment: Great - Thanks a lot! Works really perfect!